# Can't generate signed APK in GitLab CI

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm testing gitlab ci/cd and I'm trying to build a signed APK but my 
  script failed. What should I change or add?

I add variables KEYSTORE_FILE, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, KEY_ALIAS, KEY_PASSWORD 
  with values.

```
assembleRelease:
 stage: release
 script:
 - echo $KEYSTORE_FILE | base64 -d > my.keystore
 - ./gradlew assembleRelease
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$(pwd)/my.keystore
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
  artifacts:
  paths:
  - app/build/outputs/apk/release
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key  from 
store "/builds/juantamad.02072019/2019_samplebuild/my.keystore": null
```

But it should be successfully

Comment: The syntax of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` is incorrect as posted, you can try it against CI Lint

Comment: i try lint but it's the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you have correct indentations (as posted they are not), the problem is likely to be caused by multi-line command - it just executes `- ./gradlew assembleRelease` first, without further arguments

To wrap the long line you can use YAML multi-line strings:

```
  script:
   - ...
   - >
     ./gradlew assembleRelease
       -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$(pwd)/my.keystore
       -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
       -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS
       -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
```

Read more:

- [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454)
- https://gitlab.com/snippets/1717579

--

Another possible cause - if your env var is set as **Protected** in project settings,
and you are working in a branch which is **not Protected**.
Then var is not passed to your job

Comment: Another possible cause - if your env var is set as Protected in project settings, and you are working in a branch which is not Protected. Then var is not passed to your job.

Comment: it's good, but now i have different error. It said that base 64: invalid input. Should i add the extension of my keystore?

Comment: @Ivan i got this error:   $ echo -n $KEYSTORE_FILE | base64 -di > my.keystore
base64: invalid input.    can you help me, please.

Comment: I found solution. That must be like this:  - echo -n %KEYSTORE_FILE% | base64 -di > $(pwd)/my.keystore

Comment: @Ivan I got this error now:   /bin/bash: line 109: -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=/builds/Masoud799/derbiapp/my.keystore: No such file or directory.      please help me.