# assembleRelease can't generate signed apk in gitlab ci

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build signed apk with gitlab ci but i got this error:

```
/bin/bash: line 109: -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=/builds/MyGitlab/myapp/release.jks: 
No such file or directory
```

I add variables KEYSTORE_FILE, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, KEY_ALIAS, KEY_PASSWORD with values in gitlab ci/cd variable. I'm used base64 encoding of my keystore file.
My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is as below:

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

stages:
  - release

assembleRelease:
  stage: release
  script:
    - echo -n %KEYSTORE_FILE% | base64 -di > release.jks
    - >
      ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
        -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$(pwd)/release.jks
        -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS
        -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release
      - app/build/outputs/apk/prod/release
```

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?
Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879626/cant-generate-signed-apk-in-gitlab-ci) exist but I got different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shouldn’t store keystore file and credentials in version control system. We can hide credentials with creating keystore.properties file and using credentials from this file in signing config part like this:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
android {
    ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['releaseKeyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['releaseKeyPassword']
            storeFile file(rootDir.getCanonicalPath() + '/' + keystoreProperties['releaseKeyStore'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['releaseStorePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

keystore.properties contains keystore credentials:

```
releaseKeyAlias=Prod
releaseKeyPassword=12345678
releaseKeyStore=release.keystore.jks
releaseStorePassword=12345678
```

In the siging config, release.keystore.jks keystore file is used but we will not store it the vcs. So, we need to generate keystore file before building android application in continuous integration.

Developer has keystore file and app signing keys that are visible in `build.gradle`. I’ve use this solution to secure our keystore file:

**Store encrypted keystore file in version control system:**

First, create a secret key for yourself:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k ciappsigningexample-secret -P -md sha1
```

It generates salt, key and iv. We’ll use 256-bit secret key.
Then, encrypt your keystore file with your 256-bit secret key:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in debug.keystore.jks -out debug.keystore.jks.encrypted -k 99924EB44...
```

It will generate `debug.keystore.jks.encrypted` file and you can push this file to git. To decrypt your encrypted keystore in CI, you need to add your 256-bit secret key to CI as an environment. Then you can decrypt keystore file with using this secret key in pre-build step with following command:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in debug.keystore.jks.encrypted -k $DEBUG_ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY >> debug.keystore.jks
```

Comment: Hello @Masoud , Can you please help me to create the apk using above process. Please give me some suggestion , from where i need to start this, Or any link which can be helpful .Please help me on it.Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the steps by steps of the solutions